# Stack don't want to build my haskell project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build my haskell stack project (new project), but I get this

```
Writing implicit global project config file to: /home/toor/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
```

What's wrong with stack? My projects worked before

Comment: Is there a `stack.yaml` in your project directory?

Comment: No, i don't know why, but "stack new" command haven't made stack.yamal file. What can I do with it?

Comment: Did you change to the new directory after running `stack new`?

Comment: It seems you are running stack outside of the project directory

Comment: The `stack.yaml` is necessary to tell `stack` "Yes, this is a stack project" and to provide basic configuration to `stack`. See https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#yaml-configuration. If it's not present, `stack` will fall back to the "global project" configuration mentioned in the CLI output you posted. `stack new` should create a `stack.yaml`. If it didn't, the command probably failed for some reason and there should be an error message.